# javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two classes based in an xsd, Comprobante and Detallista, I filled both classes but when I want to convert my class into a xml string I get this error:

**(javax.xml.bind.MarshalException) javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList ni ninguna de sus superclases se conocen en este contexto. javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList ni ninguna de sus superclases se conocen en este contexto.]**

this is the way I filled my classes:

```
try
   {
       String cfdi="",complemento_det="";
       cFunctions functions=new cFunctions();
       ObjectMapper omapper=new ObjectMapper();
       Comprobante comprobante=new Comprobante();
       Detallista cdetallista=new Detallista();
       JSONObject jpreCFDI=new JSONObject(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(preCFDI, "UTF-8"));
       ArrayList<Object> lst_complemento=new ArrayList();
       if(jpreCFDI.has("complemento"))
       {
            JSONArray complementos=jpreCFDI.getJSONArray("complemento");
            jpreCFDI.remove("complemento");
            for(int i=complementos.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
               JSONObject jcomplemento=complementos.getJSONObject(i);
               JSONObject any=jcomplemento.getJSONObject("any");
               if(any.has("cdetallista"))
               {
                 JSONObject jcdetallista=any.getJSONObject("cdetallista");
                 cdetallista=omapper.readValue(jcdetallista.toString(),Detallista.class);
                 lst_complemento.add(cdetallista);
                 complemento_det="detallista";
               }
            }
       }
       comprobante=omapper.readValue(jpreCFDI.toString(),Comprobante.class);
       cfdi=functions.getCFDI_string(comprobante,"");
       setOriginal_string(functions.getOriginal_String(cfdi,getXlst_path())); 
       if(getOriginal_string().equals("e-cadena"))
          return new JSONObject().put("Code","afe-e05").put("Message","Error al generar cadena original").put("CFDI","");
       if(functions.getStamp_CFDI(getPassword_key_file(),getOriginal_string(),getKey_file_path()).equals("e-campos"))
          return new JSONObject().put("Code","afe-e06").put("Message","Faltan campos para generar sello digital").put("CFDI","");
       else if(functions.getStamp_CFDI(getPassword_key_file(),getOriginal_string(),getKey_file_path()).equals("e-password"))
           return new JSONObject().put("Code","afe-e07").put("Message","Contraseña incorrecta de archivo .key").put("CFDI","");
       comprobante.setSello(functions.getStamp_CFDI(getPassword_key_file(),getOriginal_string(),getKey_file_path()));
       comprobante.setCertificado(functions.getCertificated_CFDI(getCertificated_file_path()));
       Complemento complemento=new Complemento();
       complemento.getAny().add(lst_complemento);
       comprobante.getComplemento().add(complemento);
       cfdi=functions.getCFDI_string(comprobante,complemento_det);
       return new JSONObject().put("Code","afe-200").put("Message","success").put("CFDI",cfdi);
   } 
   catch(Exception ex)
    {
       String cause=ex.getLocalizedMessage();
       if(cause!=null && (cause.contains("JSONObject")||cause.contains("JSONArray")))
           return new JSONObject().put("Code","afe-e08").put("Message","Error al generar CFDI. Faltan nodos requeridos.").put("CFDI","");
        return new JSONObject().put("Code","afe-e00").put("Message","Ocurrio un error en el servidor.").put("CFDI","");
    }
```

And this is for convert the class:

```
 public String getCFDI_string(Comprobante cfdi,String complemento) throws Exception
{
   String prefix;
   JAXBContext jcontext;
   if(complemento.equals("detallista")){
     jcontext=JAXBContext.newInstance(Comprobante.class,Detallista.class);
     prefix="http://www.sat.gob.mx/detallista http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/detallista/detallista.xsd";
   }
   /*else if(complemento.equals("donat"))
   {
       jcontext=JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Comprobante.class});
   }*/
   else
   { 
       jcontext=JAXBContext.newInstance(Comprobante.class);
       prefix="";
   }
   String xml="";
   Marshaller marsh=jcontext.createMarshaller();
   marsh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
   marsh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
   marsh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3  http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd "+prefix);
   try(StringWriter swriter=new StringWriter()){
      marsh.marshal(cfdi,swriter);
      xml=swriter.toString();
   }
   return xml;
}
```

And this is the part of the class Comprobante that is causing the error:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Complemento")
protected List<Comprobante.Complemento> complemento;
public List<Comprobante.Complemento> getComplemento() {
    if (complemento == null) {
        complemento = new ArrayList<Comprobante.Complemento>();
    }
    return this.complemento;
}
public static class Complemento {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;

    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does class `Comprobante` look like (which is the type of object you are trying to marshall)? Does it have a field of type `ArrayList`? Change it to `List` (you should be programming to an interface instead of an implementation anyway).

Comment: The class Comprobante is very long to put it here